# Why is ?doing_wp_cron being appended to my URLs

Tags: urls, wp-cron

I'm finding this string appended to the end of my URLs sometimes:

```
/?doing_wp_cron
```

Does anyone know what it for? How can I remove it?

Comment: This is happening with the plugin [All In One Event Calendar](http://time.ly/). Solution in its case is to **define** `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` as **`false`** in `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a sign that you have `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` defined in your `wp-config.php`

In order to do some background processing (like publishing scheduled posts), WordPress redirects you to the URL with `?doing_wp_cron` appended.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know what I could do to get rid of that from the end of my URLs?

Comment: Remove the line from wp-config.php (although that might stop cron from working).

Comment: @scribu iThemes suggests to set up that line in the wp-config file to get BackupBuddy to work, thus removing that line again makes sure that the plugin no longer works. To your knowledge is there another "solution" to this other than dumping BackupBuddy?

Comment: @Piet: That's a rather strange requirement on the part of iThemes. A possible solution would be using UNIX cron jobs. Open a new question.

Comment: @scribu thanks for your suggestion, new question is posted: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28718/alternative-for-wp-cron-with-backupbuddy

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many posts about this problem but few of them succeed to found a real solution. What solves this problem for me has been to manage redirection in the .htaccess file.

Here is an exemple on how to redirect the url by adding these lines in the .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)doing_wp_cron= [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this will help !

Note : this tips comes from [this forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/9Db-G77bDYo)

Comment: That’s not ideal. It would be better to disable the alternative cron.

Comment: @toscho : Here is what I have understood (maybe i am missing something). the 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON' param disables cron job from Wordpress point of view. So it is disabled in the Wordpress "engine". Then the 'All in one Event Calendar' plugin, BackWPup, and all stuffes that need job schedules wont be able to proceed their jobs.
By playing with the Apache redirection, the Wordpress engine wont be affected.
That's what I figure out but not everything is clear to me. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Disabling ALTERNATE_WP_CRON doesn't disable WP internal cron (schedule) system. It only disables the alternate way to do such kind of background tasks. But, by default, WP always will do his schedule tasks unless you use the DISABLE_WP_CRON directive in your wp-config.php.

Check here to a full explanation of what ALTERNATE_WP_CRON does: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/scheduled-posts-still-not-working-in-282/#post-1163465

Comment: In order for a solution, you first need a problem. This is none.

Answer (score 1):

@scribu I believe that BackupBuddy uses WordPress task scheduling to schedule tasks as a part of the backup procedures - if the site has loopbacks disabled then the *only* solution (apart from some bespoke external solution) and the specific alternate solution that, as I am sure you know, is integrated into WordPress, is the alternate cron fix. So this is only "required" if the host has loopbacks disabled. Bear in mind that if that is the case then *no* scheduled tasks, be they standard WordPress scheduled tasks or those associated with other plugins, will work. What seems to be the case is that a user will not know that their host has hobbled their WordPress installation until they try BackupBuddy because that makes the problem obvious rather than it having been invisible until that point.

Using crontab type approach is only a sticking-plaster because, unless you make it "ping" the WordPress cron processing *very* frequently that will only work with some types of scheduled tasks.

Of course if a user doesn't want to or cannot use the alternate wp cron fix, doesn't want to move to a host that does allow loopbacks and isn't knowledgable enough to be able to set up a suitable crontab based capability then BackupBuddy does offer a manual backup mode that will work but it lacks the flexibility ana some of the capabilities of that available when scheduling is available.

Answer (score 0):

What causes this issue is alternate cron.  To workaround this, if you have access, you can enable an [actual cron process](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/insights-into-wp-cron-an-introduction-to-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/) (if your hosting will let you) and disable ALTERNATE_WP_CRON in your wp-config.php.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me and allowed me to redirect all of my posts with that on the end of the URL to the REAL URL. My host had WP_CRON set to false and ALTERNATE CRON set to true. I recall being told in the beginning that they didn't want me using WP CRON, but I had no idea how to set up jobs myself so I ignored them. In the tutorial you remove the ALTERNATE CRON and then off WP CRON, then schedule a job on your host, and add a REWRITE rule to your .htaccess file.

https://www.thewayoftheweb.net/solve-wp-cron-job-errors-caused-by-wordpress-hosting/

Now can someone help me learn how to create cron jobs? Lol or is the one I created in that tutorial all I need now?