# ”doing_wp_cron” in URL even if ALTERNATE CRON is not in wp-config

Tags: cron

The insertion of `?doing_wp_cron` in Wordpress’s URL is very well documented [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/why-is-doing-wp-cron-being-appended-to-my-urls).

My problem is a little different. I turned on the `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` feature in my `wp-config` file a few days ago. Then, noticing this issue –i.e. the introduction of `?doing_wp_cron` in my URLs– I disabled it. And by “disabled” I mean I completely removed it from the `wp-config` file. I did this 36 hours ago.

My problem is that `?doing_wp_cron` is still showing up in my access log. I wonder why? My two hypothesis are:

1) I should not remove `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` but instead I should give it the value `FALSE`

2) Those URLs are in some browsers cache and being served as such. With time they should disappear.

Feedback will be appreciated.

P.

Comment: Ok, without being sure about this, I think I found an explanation. I believe those are normal occurrences simply indicating that WordPress cron jobs are working. In my access log, they are always associated with POST request, not GET request and with the general URL of my website, not with specific posts. And I haven’t seen them in my URLs since I’ve disabled the ALTERNATE_WP_CRON Can somene familiar with access log confirm? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed with my host that this is a normal occurrence in access logs when running WordPress crons. Also, since I disabled `ALTERNATE_WP_CRON` I didn’t come across any actual (live) URLs with the `?doing_wp_cron` attached to them.